# Can I run git locally on my box and still play nicely with the company SVN repo?

Tags: git, svn, workflow

My company uses SVN for versioning. I find that I have to work on several bugs at once, which requires multiple (sometimes conflicting) changes to the same files to create an environment in which I can develop and fix. Essentially, I just want to be able to instance my workflow.

To make my work easier, I'd like to manage instances with git on my local machine, all the while using SVN to keep my local in sync with the company latest stable.

I have theorized I can do this if I create a local Main trunk, and a local "Nightly" trunk (essentially latest updated). I keep the nightly up-to-date with the latest build, the Main would act as a sort of "push point" where I can commit my changes to the company trunk. Whenever I want to create a project, I branch off the nightly, make changes, merge into the nightly, and then merge that back into my main, and commit to the SVN.

Looks something like:

```
Main    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
           \                                  /
Nightly     -------------------------------------------------------------------
                     \                /
Project               ----------------
```

And if it's not apparent, the point of the nightly would be to allow the updates I get to make their way into my projects without contaminating the Main trunk.

Would this work? Is there maybe (probably) a better solution? I'd love some feedback.

Comment: It seems rather cumbersome, at least according to this post I found on it: http://blog.evanweaver.com/2007/08/15/svn-branching-best-practices-in-practice/ . For instance, how would I manage multiple branches at once?

Answer (score 3):

You may use SVN branches by switching between them (with "svn switch") or by using several working copies as Al_G proposed.

If you really prefer Git-based solution, have a look at these tools:
 * [SubGit](http://subgit.com) --- installed on the server, creates a pure Git interface for that SVN repository. Every commit pushed to Git will be synchronized with SVN and vice versa.
 * If you have no access to the server, you may use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) or git-svn: they have similar functionality, but SmartGit translates merges (incl. cherry-picks), ignores, and tags more correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to break my answer out from the comments.

I use multiple branches all the time. Our layout has the "live/in test" in the Trunk and all development on branches. I just finished development of two new features, on branches, while bug fixing on the trunk.

Normally I create a branch (tag) for every project I'm working on and a unique directory for it. So if I have 2 projects going on it would be something like;

```
.../Trunk/
.../Branch1/
.../Branch2/
```

This saves having to do a switch every time I want to "shift" projects. As needed (at least two to three times a week) I merge from the trunk into my Branches to keep them up to date. All new work is checked into the appropriate branch. I can move between directories and "change branches" without much pain - other than disk space.

When I am cleared for merging, I re-integrate (merge) the branch back into the trunk. I'd recommend checking out [Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) in the SVN docs.

Are you using Windows, Linux, OS X, ...? You'll want to either get a good UI or script around common usage. I have a bit of both on Windows using [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) (not affiliated with either company).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Absolutely.

I have the setup that I merge (i.e. `git svn dcommit`) my stuff into a branch called `svn` that is mapped to `trunk` of the SVN repo. The whole development is done with separate branches and all the git magic.

The only important thing is that you don't accidently **rebase** your `svn` branch using `git rebase`. Think of the `svn` branch as something that could only be accessed with a limited set of functions such as

- `git svn fetch` to update the index (
- `git svn rebase` to update the index and rebase local changes onto the updated index
  (like `git pull --rebase`)
- `git svn dcommit` to push the local commits to `trunk`
  (like `git push`)

And of course, if you want to keep your git usage really secret, don't use comments such as

> fixup for 02259fd: forgot something

And don't be honest if colleagues ask questions like

> you **ALREADY** merged everything???

Further reading: [*Git Magic*, chapter *Guerilla Version Control*](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch03.html#_guerilla_version_control)